# IconButton CircleAvatar not showing image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating an AppBar for my application, but I am not able to insert an image in my CircleAvatar Button (this blue circle):

[image]

The code that I am using right now to create the CircleAvatar Button is the following one:

main.dart:

```
appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: CircleAvatar(
                    child: new Image.asset("assets/images/example.jpeg")),
                onPressed: () {}),
          ]),
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
     - assets/images/example.jpeg
```

I am trying to use this image:

[image]

So I would need to make this image appear and fit that blue CircleAvatar Button, but I cannot understand why it isn't working properly.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

P.S.: If anyone knows a package or code sample that asks the user to fit the image, in the way that he or she wants, it would be of great help to me, because I want the user to be able to fit the image in the perfect size. Like this for example:

[image]

The following error is happening:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `child` with `backgroundImage`.

So, instead of using

```
CircleAvatar(
  child: AssetImage("assets/images/example.jpeg"),
)
```

use

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/example.jpeg"),
)
```

Comment: I have tried, but the error persists, if you could have a look in the error print that I've just added, I think that the problem that I am facing would be clearer for you.

Comment: is normal `Image.asset("assets/images/example.jpeg")` working for you? I think there is some issue with your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: I've removed my pubspec.yaml and created another one, now it is working. Thanks.

Comment: I have also just come across this issue with my App.  I'm also using the backgroundImage property.  Interestingly enough the problem goes away if you use a square image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClipRRect` widget

```
ClipRRect(
  child: AssetImage("assets/images/example.jpeg"),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
)
```

Comment: Don't copy and paste the same answer by adding just one property. You said use `ClipRRect` but you copied the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio, "Invalidate caches/restart" in "File" option will work.